# How can I check if a string contains only English uppercase and lovercase letters and '|' characters?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I bag your pardon but I'm in need of any help. I must check String instance in C#. The String must contains only uppercase and lowercase English letters and '|' characters. How can I do this checking with Regex class in .NET Framework 4.5.? Suppose I got the String from Console:

```
String _processedString = Console.ReadLine();
```

How can I check it to according to above mentioned conditions?

Comment: You can use this regex: `^[a-zA-Z|]+$` to validate your input.

Comment: Why do you believe in restrictions?  Allow the user to enter anything!

Comment: This question can be filed in the category of "I don't even want to bother trying so let's see if the internet will just tell me the answer".

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
var regex = new Regex("^[A-Z|]+$");

Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("HELLO|THERE"));    // True
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("Hello"));          // False
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("HI THERE"));       // False
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("HEÎ"));            // False
```

Explanation:

`^` matches beginning of line

`[` starts one-of-these-characters matching

`A-Z` matches uppercase English letters

`|` matches the `|` character, but if it was outside the `[` `]` characters it would need to be escaped, normally `|` is the or operator.

`]` ends the one-of-these-characters matching

`+` means "one or more"

`$` means end of line